# @Mapper UnsatisfiedDependencyException while deploying

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, mapstruct

I'm getting UnsatisfiedDependecyException at `@Autowired private ApplicantDetailMapper mapper;` in service class. In service class repositories are autowried too and they are working, so assume component scan is working.

I'm clueless about this issue.

Mapper interface using spring

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ApplicantDetailMapper {

 ApplicantEntity dtoToEntity(ApplicantDto source);

}
```

Service in which it is autowired

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ApplicantDetailServiceImpl implements ApplicantDetailService {

@Autowired
private ExampleRepository repo;

@Autowired
private ApplicantDetailMapper mapper;

}
```

set up in pom.xml

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    <properties>
      <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicantDetailService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantDetailServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dtos.mappers.ApplicantDetailMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**EDIT**

Eclipse IDE For Enterprise Java Developers 2020-06

Comment: You maybe should do a clean build. As you configured, MapStruct kicks in an annotation-processing phase. An somehow the Impl class is not generated nor compiled.

Comment: tried this before, tried it again too. same problem.

Comment: fixed it. it was an eclipse problem. I will add a detailed answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation

> If you are working with the Eclipse IDE, make sure to have a current version of the
> M2E plug-in. When importing a Maven project configured as shown above, it will
> set up the MapStruct annotation processor so it runs right in the IDE, whenever
> you save a mapper type. Neat, isn’t it?
> To double check that everything is working as expected, go to your project’s
> properties and select "Java Compiler" → "Annotation Processing" → "Factory Path".
> The MapStruct processor JAR should be listed and enabled there. Any processor
> options configured via the compiler plug-in (see below) should be listed under
> "Java Compiler" → "Annotation Processing".
> If the processor is not kicking in, check that the configuration of annotation
> processors through M2E is enabled. To do so, go to "Preferences" → "Maven" →
> "Annotation Processing" and select "Automatically configure JDT APT".
> Alternatively, specify the following in the properties section of your POM file:
> <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>.
> Also make sure that your project is using Java 1.8 or later (project properties →
> "Java Compiler" → "Compile Compliance Level"). It will not work with older
> versions.

So as it says Factory Path should show MapStruct Jar listed and enabled there. In my case it wasn't there at all.

Setting  `"Automatically configure JDT APT"` caused eclipse to show Maven Update Error. with details as

> update maven encountered problem Utility Module and Dynamic Web Module 3.1 cannot both be selected.

So For me adding `<m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>` in `pom.xml properties` solved the problem.

**Source:** [MapStruct Documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/pdf/mapstruct-reference-guide.pdf)